# Windows CE datagrid button cell

Tags: windows, datagrid, windows-ce, buttonclick

I have a question. I have a datagrid and I want to add a button for deleting a row. Is is possible to display a button in datagrid. I'm running this program on windows ce operating system. I try to use it like this;

```
var f = shelfControlList.ToList();

        List<ShelfControl> sortedProductList = new List<ShelfControl>();
        sortedProductList.AddRange(f);     

        dataTable = new DataTable("InBox");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Publisher");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ButtonCell");
        dataGrid1.PreferredRowHeight = 30;
        foreach (var sp in sortedProductList)
        {
            Button deleteButton = new Button();
            deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
            deleteButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
            deleteButton.Width = 30;
            this.btnDelete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.deleteButton_Click_1);
            this.Controls.Add(deleteButton);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(sp.name, sp.publisher, deleteButton); 
        }

        dataGrid1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Thanks in advance.